# convergence of $f(x+y)$ to $f(x)$ for $y >$ to $0$ in $L^1$.

Tags: convergence-divergence

I have to show the following:
for $f \in L^1(S^1)$ Show that the map $f(x) \to f_y = f(x+y)$ is continuous in the distance of $L^1(S^1)$.
i.e.
$\lim_{y \to 0} ||f_y-f||_1 = 0$

I am supposed to use that $||f_y-f||_1 \le ||f_y-f||_\infty$ and that $L^\infty$ is dense in $L^1$. 
I do not see how one should do this properly.

I treid to do the following and would apperciate if you can say me whether this is right. 
let $ g \in L^\infty$  and continuous 
 
then we know that $g(x+y) \to g(x)$ as $ y \to 0$. 
therefore also $\sup_x g(x+y)\to g(x)$ as $y \to 0$, what means that $g(x+y)\to g(x)$ in $L^\infty$ and therefore also in $L^1$.
take $f \in L^1$ and take $\epsilon > 0$ find $g \in L^\infty$ such that $||g-f||_{L^1} < \epsilon / 3$ 
then $||f-f_y||_{L^1}=||f-g -( f_y -g_y)+g-g_y||_{L^1} \le|| f-g-(f_y-g_y)||_{L^1}+||g-g_y||_{L^1}$
where the first part is $\le 2||f-g||_{L^\infty}$ and the second $\le ||g-g_y||_{L^\infty} \le \epsilon/3$ for $y$ sufficiantly close to $x$.
so all in all $||f-f_y||_{L^1} \le \epsilon$ 
is this correct?

Comment: I don't see how the density of $L^\infty$ helps. You could (i) prove the result for continuous $f$ and then (ii) show how the general case follows.

Comment: I don't see exactly.  why is it easier to proofe it for continuous functions?

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
Show this for functions with compact support first, and generalize it after that.

Comment: He's talking about functions on the circle; every function has compact support. Compact support _per se_ doesn't help. If you meant _continuous_ functions with compact support that would work.

Comment: I still cannot see how one should proof this properly.